# I want to create a pedometer widget that updates in real time on Android

Tags: android, widget, pedometer

I want to create a pedometer widget that updates in real time on Android.

I already updated the status bar, but I don't know how to update it in the widget.
The general minimum renewal time for widgets is 30 minutes, but in other pedometer apps, widgets are updated in real time. How can I make it like that?